# Image processing on Android Platform

Tags: android, image-processing, android-emulator, imagelibrary

I am new to android platform and have to do by B Tech project on this. I have to do product recognition and then process them. So, I need to do some serious coding on implementation of Image Processing on Android platform.

For this, I would require :-

1. Through understanding of Android programming
2. Setting up the environment for image processing on Android.
3. Finally, an emulator to debug my codes

So, I need suggestions for all of the above, like, what book I should go through for learning Android , what emulators I should use and can I use openCV libraries in my android application.

Regrading emulators, I have heard, that they are pretty slow and have lots of bugs. They keep on hanging. So, should I have an Android mobile then ?

Please comment, if, you are unclear about my question.

PS: I posted the same question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28318/image-processing-on-android-platform), but got no replies. So, posted it again.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of books out there, [CommonsWare](http://commonsware.com/) is a pretty good place to start for the basics, he has office hours (where you can ask questions) and comments on here quite a lot.

There is only one emulator as far as I know, most people use eclipse for their environment and it's fairly well integrated with the android tool set, but there are a few others, as well as command line tools if your prefer those everything you need for android development is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html) other than eclipse which is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

In regards to image processing I assume you mean image matching and yes there is an [openCV for android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android) there are also some commercial offerings if you don't want to try and sort through openCV

If you are going to be using a camera to do image matching then the emulator is not a great choice unless you want to be restricted to using it with a webcam (which is a pain to get working) you will still work a lot with the emulator though.